# How to create a nested accordion in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, recursion, accordion

**Intro** -
I'm trying to show `JSON` data in a `Accordion`. So I used `react-sanfona` ([github](https://github.com/daviferreira/react-sanfona)) to build that. I'm trying to call `getComponent` function `recursively` so that I can check if it is an `array` or `object` if it is array I'm calling same function. better show you the pogress so far.

**Problem** - I'm getting `[object Object]` at the second level even I call the `getComponent` `recursively`

[Edit on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-noether-e9i1c?file=/src/styles.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that you didn't return anything when dealing with `object`

So this part

```
  Object.keys(record).map((key, index) => {
    console.log(44);
    return (
      <AccordionItem className="ml-5" title={`1 - ${index}`} expanded>
        {getComponent(record[key])}
      </AccordionItem>
    );
  });
```

should be

```
  return Object.keys(record).map((key, index) => {
    console.log(44);
    return (
      <AccordionItem className="ml-5" title={`1 - ${index}`} expanded>
        {getComponent(record[key])}
      </AccordionItem>
    );
  });
```

I added a default `expanded` property and now it displays all data.

Check
[this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-yalow-jmc0c)

Comment: Oh thank you very much. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hy, I don't know exactly what you want to display but here is a version working.

```
import { Accordion, AccordionItem } from "react-sanfona";
import "./styles.css";

const datalist = [
  {
    id: 3423235234,
    name: "John",
    address: [
      {
        first: "city1",
        second: "city2"
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default function App() {
  function getComponent(record) {
    if (Array.isArray(record)) {
      return record.map((b, index) => (
        <AccordionItem className="ml-5" title={`${index}`} key={index}>
          {getComponent(b)}
        </AccordionItem>
      ));
    }
    if (typeof record === "object") {
      return (
        <div>
          {Object.keys(record).map((key, index) => {
            return (
              <AccordionItem
                className="ml-5"
                title={`1 - ${index}`}
                expanded
                key={index}
              >
                {getComponent(record[key])}
              </AccordionItem>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (typeof record === "string" || typeof record === "number") {
      console.log("string or number: ", record);
      return <AccordionItem className="ml-5" title={`2 - ${record}`} />;
    }

    return (
      <AccordionItem className="ml-5" title={`3 - ${record.toString()}`} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="px-7">
        <Accordion>{getComponent(datalist)}</Accordion>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The package you're using raise many errors in the console (with no configuration). Did you check the material ui's accordions ? https://material-ui.com/components/accordion/

Comment: Thanks for the help but I need to show these data like json type but in a component. In your answer also its not nesting address array.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code, which might help you
Here, initially root folder will be hiding all children once click on root -> its direct children will be displayed/hidden and so on

```js
//explorer is the json coming from parent component
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Accodian({ explorer }) {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  if (explorer.children) {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* {explorer.children ? ( */}
        <>
          <div onClick={() => setExpand((prevState) => !prevState)}>
            {explorer.name}
          </div>
          {expand ? (
            <>
              {explorer.children.map((child) => {
                // return <div key={child.name} style = {{paddingLeft: '20px'}}>{child.name}</div>;
                return <Accodian explorer={child} key={child.name} />;
              })}
            </>
          ) : null}
        </>
        {/* ) : null} */}
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <div style={{ paddingLeft: "20px" }}>{explorer.name}</div>;
  }
}

export default Accodian;
```

Check this sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/js-recursion-accordian-v03y5q?file=/src/components/Accordian.js:0-823/